# KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER having \n causes two new lines

Tags: android, android-edittext, newline

I am using Edittext and I have KEYCODE_ENTER listener for it.

```
     emojiconEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            emojiconEditText.append("\n");
            return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here "\n" is causing two newlines like "\n" + "\n". But I want only one newline.
I am using input type = text multi line.

Comment: WHy would you do this at all?  The default behavior for an enter is to add a newline.

Comment: @Gabe I am calling another method on KeyEvent. So I want both things to happen, that is newline as well as method to run.

Comment: So just return false. That way the default chain will handle it still. No need to spend the newline yourself

Comment: Although the below answer about up and down events is correct, and something you'll need to account for either way

Comment: @Gabe yes below solution worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This key event is fired two times.
First when user push down enter, second when user push up enter.
So You must add some additional assertion like this.

```
 event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
```

Comment: let me try this.